# Close Window After Google Sign In

Tags: javascript

I have created a Google Form with Google Forms Tool v2. I have created a link that opens a new window to log into Google (`accounts.google.com/AddSession`). I would like it so that after you log in, it immediately closes the window. I have tried this, but it does not work the way I planned:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="var popWindow = window.open('https://accounts.google.com/AddSession#identifier', '', 'width=721, height=589'); setInterval(function () {if (popWindow.location.href != 'https://accounts.google.com/AddSession#identifier' || popWindow.location.href != 'https://accounts.google.com/AddSession#password') { popWindow.close(); }}, 1);">login</a>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: Instead, it immediately closes the window. You may want to try yourself. I use [http://htmledit.squarefree.com/](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/).

Comment: The reason being, Google opens it based on something else.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I'm kinda a noob in this stuff. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
popWindow.location.href != 'https://accounts.google.com/AddSession#identifier' || popWindow.location.href != 'https://accounts.google.com/AddSession#password'
```

Give:

```
popWindow.location.href.indexOf("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin") === 0
```

Comment: Actually, my console says 'Unexpected token }'

Comment: Yes, I do have full code. The page does not yet have the new login. All the login link does is open the window, then after you log in, it goes to My Account. The website is [here](http://lifewithzooza.x10host.com/growupform/).